# Grant user insert permission after create table command

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

What is the T-SQL syntax for granting a specific user only insert permission after a create table command?

Here is my `CREATE TABLE` script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] (
    [MyColumn1] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [MyColumn2] [char] (1) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
GRANT INSERT ON [dbo].[MyTable] TO BillyBob
```

Or something vaguely similar...

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me...note the square brackets used on the user group which didn't work without them (because of the slash).

```
USE AutoX
GRANT INSERT ON [dbo].[TBL_AUTOX_USER_ACTIVITY] TO [NAM\APP_AUTOX_USERS]
```

Comment: Thanks!  We have a dot in the service account names and your post saved me.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GRANT INSERT ON OBJECT::Person.Address TO RosaQdM;
GO
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx) for more information.